# Dihedral group as inner semidirect product

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find two subgroups $H,K$ of $D_{2n}$, the dihedral group, with $H \lhd K$, where $HK =  D_{2n}$ and the intersection of $H$ and $K$ is trivial. I have found that $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to semidirect products of cyclic subgroups of order $n$ and $2n$, or just $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_n$, but neither of these are subgroups of $D_{2n}$. Another option is $\{e,s\}$ and $\{e, r, r^2, \ldots, r^{n-1}\}$, whose intersection is $\{e\}$ and whose product is $D_{2n}$, but I don't believe that either of the subgroups are normal.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you want $H\triangleleft G$, not $H\triangleleft K$. If you had $H\triangleleft K$ (or even $H\leq K$) then $HK=K$.

Comment: To paraphrase Neil DeGrasse Tyson, the good thing about math is that it’s true whether you believe it or not. Doesn’t matter whether you believe it is normal or not, the subgroup generated by $r$ has index $2$, hence is perforce normal. Also, while $D_{2n}$ does not contain the integers modulo $n$ or the integers modulo $2$, it does contain *cyclic* groups of order $n$ and $2$, which are a better archetype than “integers modulo $n$” anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The group $D_{2n}$ has a normal subgroup consisting of $n$ rotations $\rho,...,\rho^n=1$ and a subgroup of order 2 generated by a reflection $a$.
These subgroups are forming a semidirect product of order $2n$,
so $D_{2n}$ is the semidirect product of these subgroups.

For some $n$ there are other ways to represent $D_{2n}$ as
a semidirect product.
For example $D_8$ is isomorphic to the wreath product $C_2\wr C_2=(C_2\times C_2)\rtimes C_2$.